# How to display log scale on data that are already in log?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some logarithmic data:

```
x = np.log2(np.random.randint(1, 100000, size=100))
y = np.log2(np.random.randint(1, 100000, size=100))
```

If I display it I don't get log scales:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.grid()
```

[image]

Instead I want the same dataset to be plotted with a logarithmic grid. The only way I've found is this one:

```
plt.scatter(2**x, 2**y)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.xscale("log")
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='#999999', linestyle='-', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Any better option?

Comment: Your approach looks the perfect way to do this. Only in case `2**x` would be too large to be represented in floating point you'd need much more complicated workarounds.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach? `.xscale('log')` / `.yscale('log')` works perfectly fine, doesn't it?

Comment: What is wrong is you compute twice the log value... Doing `2**log2(x)` is quite ugly